# Random Source Games Stop Working After Kernel Update

Tags: nvidia, games, steam, bumblebee

I am a noob of Xubuntu (and Linux) for 2 months, and I have been relying on my brother who is a fluent user of Linux. 
I have downloaded and installed the latest kernel update, `linux-image-3.16.0-41-generic`, and all of the other stuff that it needed. So after that, a few of my Source games stop working under `optirun`. The only games that I have that work are "Double Action: Boogaloo" and "Counter-Strike: Source".

Note: I have all the Counter-Strike games (sans Nexus), GMod and Portal 2.

CS:GO's Error

```
~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive$ optirun ./csgo_linux 
./csgo_linux: error while loading shared libraries: libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

GMod's Error

```
~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/GarrysMod$ optirun ./hl2_linux
AppFramework : Unable to load module /home/USERNAME/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/common/GarrysMod/bin/filesystem_stdio.so!
```

Portal 2 throws the same error as CS:GO.

I have `bumblebee` and `nvidia-349` installed (and all the dependencies). I've installed NVidia drivers via [this method](http://rajat-osgyan.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-driver-in.html), and have installed the 32-bit libraries via [this method.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005) Please help!

EDIT: This also happens without `optirun` (with Intel integrated graphics).

UPDATE: I ran `steam` in the console (not the games themselves) and then ran the games. I saw in most of the logs this:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pistol/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/pistol/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

**The Actual Fix**

All credit goes to Henrik Johansson who made a great guide [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/535927/ubuntu-14-04-bumblebee-optimus-error-with-steam) I'll tell you what to do in short.

For Valve games, go to the executable in your favorite editor and search for

```
 ${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
```

and replace it with

```
primusrun ${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
```

(or `optirun`, your choice)

This seems to affect all games that utilize a `.sh` executable. Other games may be fixed in a similar fashion.

**My Explanation**

The problem lies within how Steam runs commands. This is a problem I have just recently connected the dots with and now know the answer. It seems as if the `ld.so` problem deals with Intel drivers (or so I think). Steam fails to run `optirun`/`primusrun` correctly (or maybe *at all*) and thus uses the Intel drivers, which doesn't work.

That which is below is not applicable anymore, as `xorg-edgers` is now `graphics-drivers`.

### Don't listen to what's below this, please.

---

After multiple search attempts on the internet and after LOTS of trial and error, I can safely conclude that the main problem is the PPA `xorg-edgers`. If you have similar problems, you should remove whatever drivers you have from `xorg-edgers` and then `ppa-purge` it.

If you don't know how to do it, then here's how.

Install `ppa-purge` by...

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Remove the `xorg-edgers` with...

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

And finally...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the game complains about the absence of `libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4` library. Probably, Steam or the game have their version of this lib inside the directory. Anyway, you can try install it from the Ubuntu repository. I don't now if it uses the 32 bits or 64 bits version, but you can try:

For the 64 bits version

```
sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal
```

or the 32 bits version

```
sudo apt-get install libtcmalloc-minimal4:i386
```

In the second case, it complains that, for any reason, it can't load the file filesystem_stdio.so inside the steam instalation. You can try reinstall steam.

Comment: Yeah... optirunning CS:GO still doesn't work in Steam, but when I do it in the console, it says I'm in VAC-insecure mode.  GMod throws the same error as before.